# UITabBarのアイコン画像がジャギる

Tags: swift, uiimageview

UITabBarのTabBarItemにに24pxの[アイコン画像](https://icons8.com/web-app/for/all/home)を表示させているのですが、画像がジャギります（縁がかくかくになります）。滑らかなアイコン画像をタブに表示したいです。

基本的に画像は使用するサイズのものを用意すると思うのですが、IOSでは
UITabBarの画像しかりUIImageViewには大きめの画像を縮小して使うのがベストプラクティスなのでしょうか？

https://icons8.com/web-app/for/all/home

ここから無料でダウンロードできるアイコン画像がもともとジャギーなものだからでしょうか？どのアイコン画像もかくかくになるので困っています。

お時間いただける方よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retina対応するのであれば、fileName@2x.pngとする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。表示させたいサイズの倍の画像（今回だと48px）を用意してfileName@2x.pngで保存したらうまくいきました。